# Can't install PuLP in Anaconda

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, pulp

Python newbie here. I am trying to install PuLP. So I do a `pip install Pulp` in conda command prompt and looks like pulp gets installed. I run a `conda list` and I can see that PuLP is there in the list (please see image).

However, when I try importing PuLP in IDLE,i get an error and I also can't see PuLP in the list of environments in Anaconda navigator (not sure if I am supposed to).

If Pulp is in the list, why can't I import it or see it in Navigator. Any inputs will be appreciated.

Comment: Might help to tag this with `pip` or `anaconda`

Comment: PuLP in Anaconda is supported up to v. 3.6 as of the end of August 2020. There may also be an incompatibility between your selected Python version and PuLP package. However, as pointed out below, `pip install` within an activated Anaconda environment works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

> conda install -c conda-forge pulp

Answer (score 1):

You have installed an *standalone* `Python`, and *other* `Python` with `Anaconda`.

First, if you installed a package by the `pip`, it is O.K. that it is *not displayed* in installed packages in Anaconda environment(s) (as you installed it out of `Anaconda`) and at the same time it is fully functional.

Second, you have to install `PuLP` *again* for your standalone `Python` (with the same `pip install` command - this time *not* in `conda` command prompt, but directly in you OS console / terminal / DOS-prompt (depends of your OS).